# Does anyone know what set this is from? Possibly Star Wars, lots of greys

Tags: set-identification

From a friend, we have what looks like a Star Wars set of 9 bags. Bag one is missing, but I think it was just built as this. The bags say 2011 and 135149. Thanks!

[image: bag 1 of Star Wars Set]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like [75093-1 Death Star Final Duel](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75093-1)

Based on:

- Light Bluish Gray Technic, Liftarm, Modified Bent Thick L-Shape 2 x 4
- Dark Bluish Gray Slope, Curved 2 x 2 x 2/3
- Light Bluish Gray Plate, Modified 1 x 4 with 2 Studs without Groove

[image: 75093-1 Death Star Final Duel]

Comment: That Trans-Light Blue Plate, Round 1 x 1 is in the inventory, as is the Light Bluish Gray Technic, Axle 1L with Tow Ball, and the Light Bluish Gray Brick, Round 1 x 1 Open Stud, and the hinges, and the White Brick, Modified 1 x 2 with Pin, but not that blue-like cheese slope in the top right...

Comment: ... or is that just a weird reflection on a Dark Bley piece?

Comment: Omg, that is it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @RSchulz : looks like a reflection to me. The shadows indicate a light source that is just about the right angle to reflect off that cheese slope into the camera.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I'm so glad I didn't spend time hunting for that piece as a Light Blue or Sand Blue or Medium Azure or whatever color it *seems* to be...

Comment: It's called bluish grey for a reason I guess :)